# How to merge multiple jsonp requests in a backbone.js model sync?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

## What am I trying to achieve?

There is a I am trying to update a nice jenkins radiator application made by Clayton Lengel-Zigich.  It is a backbone.js application that fetches the status of a jenkins master server using its jsonp api and displays job status.  I want to change this application to fetch from multiple masters and show the status for many jobs.

## What have I tried?

I have tried to update the sync function to do two jsonp requests and then merge the result.  The original file can be found here: https://github.com/clayton/jenkins-radiator/blob/master/src/radiator.js

```
sync: function(method, model, options) {

      var paramsA = _.extend({
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          processData: true,
          url: "http://serverA:8080/api/json?jsonp=?"
      }, options);
      var a = $.ajax(paramsA);


      var paramsB = _.extend({
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          processData: true,
          url: "http://serverB:8080/api/json?jsonp=?"
      }, options);
      var b = $.ajax(paramsB);

      function MergeJobs(o, ob) {
        for (var z in ob.jobs) {
           o.jobs.push(ob.jobs[z]);
        }
        return o;
      }

      var joinedJson = []
      a.done(function(jsonA) {
        joinedJson = jsonA;
      });
      b.done(function(jsonB) {
        MergeJobs(joinedJson, jsonB);
        //joinedJson = jsonB;
      })
      return joinedJson;

  },
```

## What I got

I expected that I would be able to see the merged results in the webpage however I only see the results for one of the servers.  Which server gets displayed is random, indicating to me that my merge is overwriting, not merging.

I don't know a lick of javascript so I am at the stage where I don't even know where to look next.  Perhaps the _.extend section is what actually updates the model? If so, is there a way to achieve what I want another way?

Comment: Since you are still making seperate requests, why not create a different models for your servers and avoid overwriting the sync?

Comment: If I create seperate models can I still display them on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate models and display them on the same If the models have the same structure I suggest you create an array containing all your models and then pass them to a collection. If your models are totally different then pass them to a view and have some logic in the view to handle all your models.

This site (http://backbonetutorials.com/) has some great tutorials to get started with models and collections just in case you haven't used backbone that much.

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee as to which of your requests finishes first. If B finishes before A, it will merge `jsonB` into the empty `joinedJson` (simply setting it to `jsonB`) and then when A finishes it will overwrite `joinedJson` with `jsonA`.

That's not your only problem; at the time you return `joinedJson` there's no guarantee that *either* request has finished; you're treating asynchronous requests as if they were synchronous.